# Select Count multiple table sql server return 1 value

Tags: sql-server

I have problem with my multiple count.

here my table

```
table1
ID UserId Username
1    a      aa
2    b      bb
3    c      cc
4    d      dd

table2
ID UserId2  note  
1   1       n1
2   1       n2
3   2       n3
4   2       n4 

table3
ID UserId3  testname
1    1      test1
2    1       test2
3    2       test3
4    2       test4
5    3       test 5

table4 

ID UserId  filename
1   1        filea
2   1        fileb
3   2        filec
4   2        filed
```

I have query like this

```
    select ID, userID, username, 
    (select count(distinct table2.ID) from table2 where table2.userID2 = ID group by userID,username) as note_count , 
    (select count(distinct table3.ID) from table3 where table3.userID3 = ID group by userID,username) as PO_count,
select filename from table4 where table3.userID = table1.ID group by filename) as FileCount   
    from table1 ORDER BY userID
```

the select count from table3 is working well, but for count table2 just return `1` value for each row. and I need the filecount group by filename from table4, how to do that?  I have an error on subquery.

Comment: I don't think you need the `GROUP BY` in the sub query, and I would recommend qualifying ID.  This applies to both sub queries, but for example: `(select count(distinct table3.ID) from table3 where table3.userID3 = table1.ID ) as PO_count`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    note_count = ISNULL(DISTINCT COUNT(t2.ID), 0),
    PO_count = ISNULL(DISTINCT COUNT(t3.ID), 0)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.UserId2 = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
    ON t3.UserId3 = t1.ID
GROUP BY
    t1.ID, t1.UserId, t1.Username
ORDER BY t1.UserId
```

Or you can use `CROSS APPLY`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/660/0)

```
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    t2.note_count,
    t3.po_count
FROM table1 t1
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT note_count = COUNT(*)
    FROM table2
    WHERE UserId2 = t1.ID
)t2
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT po_count = COUNT(*)
    FROM table3
    WHERE UserId3 = t1.ID
)t3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues here:-

1. You don't really need the `GROUP BY` statements in your two subqueries.
2. The `ID` in the `WHERE` clauses of your sub query should aliased so that they are correctly linked to `table1`.

eg

```
SELECT ID
   ,UserId
   ,Username
   ,(SELECT count(DISTINCT table2.ID)
       FROM table2
      WHERE table2.UserId2 = t.ID) AS note_count
   ,(SELECT count(DISTINCT table3.ID)
       FROM table3
      WHERE table3.UserId3 = t.ID
      ) AS PO_count
FROM table1 t
ORDER BY UserId
```

3. As a matter of convention, it is a good idea to keep the casing of your tables and column names consistent. If you were to install your query on a case-sensitive installation of SQL Server, this query would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you're doing a `count(DISTINCT ID)`.  That should be your key and different for every record anyway.  This would leave you just needing this.

```
SELECT
    u.ID,
    u.UserName,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table2
        WHERE UserId2 = u.Id) AS note_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table3
        WHERE UserId3 = u.Id) AS test_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table4
        WHERE UserId4 = u.Id) AS file_count
FROM
    table1 u
```

On the other hand, if for example `User 1` can take `test1` more than once, but you only want the distinct count of `testname`, you would change the test_count query to

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT testname)
    FROM table3
    WHERE UserId3 = u.Id) AS test_count,
```

Same for files and notes

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT
    ID,
    userID,
    username, 
    (SELECT COUNT(t2.ID)    FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.userID2 = t1.ID) AS note_count, 
    (SELECT COUNT(t3.ID)    FROM table3 t3 WHERE t3.userID3 = t1.ID) AS PO_count,
    LTRIM(ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT 
                            ', ' + filename + ' (' + CAST(COUNT(filename) AS VARCHAR) + ')'
                        FROM
                            table4 t4
                        WHERE
                            t4.userID = t1.ID
                        GROUP BY
                            filename
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        )
                        , 1, 1,''),'-'))
                AS FileCount
FROM
    table1 t1
ORDER BY
    t1.UserId
```

Comment: this nice, but I need the count(filename) group by filename from table4.

Comment: actually, I need sum the count while the group by filename

Comment: Please try the updated query. check whether it is useful or not. If you dont want like this, you need to use JOIN with Filecount query with outer query. But duplicate user details row will be shown.